# Values lost with PHP multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got troubles with multidimensional array in PHP because I lost some values when I try to add other informations in my array.

Here is my initial code :

```
$reponse = $bdd->query("select OrderDate, NomChaine, NomJob, Debut, Fin from ReportJobs where NomJob in ('NPT01000', 'NPT11999') order by OrderDate ASC;");
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
    $num_semaine = date('W', strtotime($donnees['OrderDate']));
    $num_journee = date('N', strtotime($donnees['OrderDate']));

    $retour[$num_semaine][$num_journee][substr($donnees['NomChaine'], 0, -2)][$donnees['NomJob']] = array(
        'Debut' => $donnees['Debut'],
        'Fin' => $donnees['Fin']
    );
}
$reponse->closeCursor();
var_dump($retour['07']['1']);
```

Here is the (correct and wanted) output of the `var_dump($retour['07']['1']);` :
[image]

---

Then, I tried to store the value of 'OrderDate' in the `$retour[$num_semaine][$num_journee]` level.

Here is the new code :

```
$reponse = $bdd->query("select OrderDate, NomChaine, NomJob, Debut, Fin from ReportJobs where NomJob in ('NPT01000', 'NPT11999') order by OrderDate ASC;");
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
    $num_semaine = date('W', strtotime($donnees['OrderDate']));
    $num_journee = date('N', strtotime($donnees['OrderDate']));

    $retour[$num_semaine][$num_journee] = array(
        'Date' => $donnees['OrderDate']
    );
    $retour[$num_semaine][$num_journee][substr($donnees['NomChaine'], 0, -2)][$donnees['NomJob']] = array(
        'Debut' => $donnees['Debut'],
        'Fin' => $donnees['Fin']
    );
}
$reponse->closeCursor();
var_dump($retour['07']['1']);
```

`var_dump($retour['07']['1']);` :
[image]

Some values are now missing.

---

I tried it the other way around :

```
$reponse = $bdd->query("select OrderDate, NomChaine, NomJob, Debut, Fin from ReportJobs where NomJob in ('NPT01000', 'NPT11999') order by OrderDate ASC;");
while ($donnees = $reponse->fetch())
{
    $num_semaine = date('W', strtotime($donnees['OrderDate']));
    $num_journee = date('N', strtotime($donnees['OrderDate']));

    $retour[$num_semaine][$num_journee][substr($donnees['NomChaine'], 0, -2)][$donnees['NomJob']] = array(
        'Debut' => $donnees['Debut'],
        'Fin' => $donnees['Fin']
    );
    $retour[$num_semaine][$num_journee] = array(
        'Date' => $donnees['OrderDate']
    );
}
$reponse->closeCursor();
var_dump($retour['07']['1']);
```

`var_dump($retour['07']['1']);` :
[image]

It looks like the second instructions erased all the things written with the first one.

---

Anyone got an idea on how I can make this right ?
Thanks to all of you who read till the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With this line....

```
$retour[$num_semaine][$num_journee] = array(
    'Date' => $donnees['OrderDate']
);
```

... you reassign a new array each time (to the given element). One obvious idea is to change it into this:

```
$retour[$num_semaine][$num_journee]['Date'] = $donnees['OrderDate'];
```

... so your code will be adjusting the array element (array itself) that exists already.

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't that obvious to me in the first place. :-D